# Problem with PHP regular expressions

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

I just can't seem to work out how to pull the entire table from a page using regex.

**This is my PHP:**

```
$printable = file_get_contents('http://entertainment.soundboxaudio.com/testplaylist.htm');
$array = array();
preg_match( '/<TABLE>(.*?)<\/TABLE>/si', $printable, $array ) ;
$findit = "$array[1]";
echo("$findit");
```

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: use a HTML parser instead. [`DomDocument::loadHTML()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) does it well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here we go again... do NOT use regex to extract HTML. HTML is not a regular language and cannot be reliably analyzed with a regex. Use DOM instead.

```
$printable = file_get_conttents('...');
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($printable);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$tables = $xpath->query("//table");

$table_html = array();

foreach($tables as $table) { // workaround for PHP DOM not support innerHTML
   $temp = new DOMDocument;
   $temp->appendChild($temp->importNode($table, true));
   $table_html[] = trim($temp->saveHTML());
}
```

As well, surrounding variables you're echoing is just a waste of a string operation

```
echo $x
echo "$x";
```

work identically, except the quoted version wastes some cpu produce a temporary string that only gets thrown away again.

Comment: Verify that you're actually getting some html back by doing a `var_dump($printable)`.

Comment: I'm getting the html (I also corrected the contents), still nothing.

Comment: As a side note: all the HTML in the document is printed in uppercase.

Comment: in that case, use `//TABLE` instead for the xpath query. XPath is case sensitive, since the underlying XML is as well.

Comment: Well, no wonder. That page you're testing on is generated by MSHTML. The last turd you dropped into the toilet can generate better HTMl than Microsoft HTML. It's completely invalid HTML and PHP's DOM parser does NOT like working on malformed html. You'll have to clean up the HTML first, or pass it through Tidy to get it into some semblance of valid html.

Comment: How would I clean it up? The document is automatically generated.

Comment: @MarcB let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2623/discussion-between-alexwhin-and-marc-b)